# Invalid mount config for type "bind"

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have the following services in docker-compose:

```
nginx-certificate:
    build:
      context: ./nginx-certificate
    container_name: aloware-nginx-certificate
    restart: no
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: ./certs
        target: /etc/nginx/ssl

node:
    build:
      context: ./node
    container_name: aloware-node
    restart: unless-stopped
    depends_on:
      # nginx-certificate:
      #   condition: service_completed_successfully
      node-builder:
        condition: service_completed_successfully
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: ${BASE_PATH}
        target: /var/www/api-core
      - type: bind
        source: ./certs/nginx-local.alodev.org.crt
        target: /root/.config/valet/Certificates/local.alodev.org:8081.crt
      - type: bind
        source: ./certs/nginx-local.alodev.org.key
        target: /root/.config/valet/Certificates/local.alodev.org:8081.key
    ports:
      - protocol: tcp
        published: ${NODE_PORT}
        target: 8081
      - protocol: tcp
        published: ${NODE_BROWSERSYNC_PORT}
        target: 3001
    working_dir: /var/www/api-core
    command: [ "npm", "run", "watch" ]
    networks:
      frontend:
        aliases:
          - aloware-node
      backend:
        aliases:
          - aloware-node
```

The first service generate a certificate that I need to use in Node service but I have the bind volumen where the path of the certificates don't exists. I need to execute the nginx-certificate.

Comment: Can you make the generation step have the right filenames, so you can just mount the `./certs` directory into both containers?  I might guess the colon `:` in the filename causes problems, since in some mount syntaxes it's a separator between paths and options.

Comment: Is `${BASE_PATH}` an exported variable? What is its value? Try setting it to a fixed value (variables may not be expanded there).